# ERROR: Cannot uninstall PyQt5 5.15.6, RECORD file not found. Hint: The package was installed by sip-build

Tags: apt, package-management, python, 22.04, pyqt5

I'm trying to debunk a real mess with PyQt5 on Ubuntu 22.04, it seems I reach a point where I cannot uninstall it, and I am wondering *why* exactly this is not possible, throwing me the following error:

```
$ sudo -H pip3 uninstall PyQt5
Found existing installation: PyQt5 5.15.6
ERROR: Cannot uninstall PyQt5 5.15.6, RECORD file not found. Hint: The package was installed by sip-build.
```

Installed files are:

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PyQt5
Qt5  sip.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

More infos:

```
$ sudo -H pip3 list | grep -i qt
PyQt5                         5.15.6
PyQt5-Qt5                     5.15.2
PyQt5-sip                     12.11.0
PyQtWebEngine                 5.15.5
QtAwesome                     1.1.1
qtconsole                     5.3.0
QtPy                          2.2.0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3
```

How could I properly uninstall the custom PyQt5 (under /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ , notice the **local** part)?

This is not about removing `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5` because this folder is the one use by the system package manager for installing the official apt package `python3-pyqt5`. Indeed, by doing that, it will break many other stuff:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove --purge python3-pyqt5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fonts-lyx* grass-core* grass-doc* libassimp5* libclang1-14* libdraco4* libfcgi-bin* libfcgi0ldbl* libjs-leaflet* liblaszip8* liblbfgsb0* libpdal-base13* libpdal-plugin-draco* libpdal-plugin-e57*
  libpdal-plugin-faux* libpdal-plugin-hdf* libpdal-plugin-i3s* libpdal-plugin-icebridge* libpdal-plugin-pgpointcloud* libpdal-plugins* libpdal-util13* libqca-qt5-2* libqca-qt5-2-plugins* libqgis-3d3.26.2*
  libqgis-analysis3.26.2* libqgis-app3.26.2* libqgis-core3.26.2* libqgis-customwidgets* libqgis-gui3.26.2* libqgis-native3.26.2* libqgis-server3.26.2* libqgisgrass7-3.26.2* libqgispython3.26.2*
  libqscintilla2-qt5-15* libqscintilla2-qt5-l10n* libqt53danimation5* libqt53dcore5* libqt53dextras5* libqt53dinput5* libqt53dlogic5* libqt53dquickscene2d5* libqt53drender5* libqt5charts5* libqt5concurrent5*
  libqt5designer5* libqt5designercomponents5* libqt5help5* libqt5keychain1* libqt5location5* libqt5opengl5* libqt5pdf5* libqt5positioningquick5* libqt5qml5* libqt5qmlmodels5* libqt5quick5* libqt5quickwidgets5*
  libqt5sensors5* libqt5sql5* libqt5sql5-sqlite* libqt5test5* libqt5webchannel5* libqt5webengine-data* libqt5webengine5* libqt5webenginecore5* libqt5webenginewidgets5* libqt5webkit5* libqwt-qt5-6* libre2-9*
  libspatialindex6* libsqlite3-mod-spatialite* libxsimd-dev* libzip4* pyqt5-dev-tools* python-babel-localedata* python-matplotlib-data* python3-babel* python3-beniget* python3-brotli* python3-cycler*
  python3-decorator* python3-fonttools* python3-fs* python3-gast* python3-ipython-genutils* python3-jinja2* python3-jsonschema* python3-jupyter-core* python3-kiwisolver* python3-lz4* python3-matplotlib*
  python3-mpmath* python3-nbformat* python3-owslib* python3-pbr* python3-plotly* python3-ply* python3-psycopg2* python3-pyproj* python3-pyqt5* python3-pyqt5.qsci* python3-pyqt5.qtpositioning*
  python3-pyqt5.qtsql* python3-pyqt5.qtsvg* python3-pyqt5.qtwebchannel* python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine* python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit* python3-pyrsistent* python3-pythran* python3-qgis* python3-qgis-common* python3-scipy*
  python3-sip* python3-sympy* python3-tenacity* python3-traitlets* python3-ufolib2* python3-unicodedata2* qdoc-qt5* qgis* qgis-common* qgis-plugin-grass* qgis-plugin-grass-common* qgis-provider-grass*
  qgis-providers* qgis-providers-common* qhelpgenerator-qt5* qml-module-qtcharts* qt3d-assimpsceneimport-plugin* qt3d-defaultgeometryloader-plugin* qt3d-gltfsceneio-plugin* qt3d-scene2d-plugin* qt5-assistant*
  qt5-image-formats-plugin-pdf* qtattributionsscanner-qt5* qttools5-dev-tools* unicode-data*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 136 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1’060 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

I was always told and used to use the `-H` flag with `sudo` so that packages do not overlap the ones installed by `apt`, installing them in the `/usr/local/lib/...` path instead of `/usr/lib/...`, but with PyQt5, the uninstall command seems it want to uninstall the `apt` package instead... Why? Because if I manually remove the PyQT5 folder within `/usr/local/lib/...` :

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PyQt5*
```

and then try to redo the installation, I face the same error, with a little more verbosity:

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install -U PyQt5
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.15.6)
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.7-cp37-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (8.4 MB)
Collecting PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.11
  Using cached PyQt5_sip-12.11.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (359 kB)
Collecting PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15.0
  Using cached PyQt5_Qt5-5.15.2-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (59.9 MB)
Installing collected packages: PyQt5-Qt5, PyQt5-sip, PyQt5
  Attempting uninstall: PyQt5
    Found existing installation: PyQt5 5.15.6
ERROR: Cannot uninstall PyQt5 5.15.6, RECORD file not found. Hint: The package was installed by sip-build.
```

But without the `-U` (`--upgrade`) flags, it does well:

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install PyQt5
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.15.6)
Collecting PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.8
  Using cached PyQt5_sip-12.11.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (359 kB)
Installing collected packages: PyQt5-sip
Successfully installed PyQt5-sip-12.11.0
```

which actually creates the folder we previously manually deleted: `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PyQt5/`

The same procedure works very well with plenty of other Python packages, but apparently not PyQt5.

For example with numpy I have both
`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/` (1.21.5) and
`/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/` (1.23.2).